# How to implement my de-dupe code into batch apex?

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits, dml, merge

My anonymous de-dupe Account apex code runs successfully until it hits a DML limit on the merge execution.  I do not want to reduce the size of my query.  How do I implement this in batch apex so that it is aware of governor limits?

In particular, I want it to run in batches of appropriate size so that it can complete without giving me "too many DML statements".

```
// Assumption is accounts exist with dupe DunsNumber

List<Account> allMasters = [SELECT Id, DunsNumber FROM Account WHERE CreatedBy.LastName!='Smith' AND DunsNumber!=null];
List<Account> allPotentialDupes = [SELECT Id, DunsNumber FROM Account WHERE CreatedBy.LastName='Smith' AND DunsNumber!=null];

Map<Account, List<Account>> mastersDupes = new Map<Account, List<Account>>();

for (Account master : allMasters){
    List<Account> mSDupes = new List<Account>();
    for (Account dupe : allPotentialDupes){
        if(master.DunsNumber == dupe.DunsNumber){ //dupe account identified so add it to the mastersDupes list
            mSDupes.add(dupe);
        }
    }

    mastersDupes.put(master, mSDupes);

}

for (Account masterAcct : mastersDupes.keySet()) { //for every key in mastersDupes
    List<Account> keysDupeList = new List<Account>();
    keysDupeList.addAll(mastersDupes.values()[0]);
    for (Account mergeAcct : keysDupeList) //mergeAcct with the masterAcct
    {
        try {
        merge masterAcct mergeAcct;
        } catch (DmlException e) {
        // Process exception
        System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't implement Batchable, Queueable, or Schedulable in an execute anonymous script. You'll either get an Internal Server Error or a "only top level classes can implement X interface" errors. You'll need to write a proper class, deploy it to production, and then run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just using an anonymous script and trying to knock this task out quickly, you can add a limits check and just bail once you've performed the maximum number of `DML Statements`.

```
for (...)
{
    if (Limits.getLimitDmlStatements() > Limits.getDmlStatements())
    {
        merge ...
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, can we use `getLimitDMLRows()` for this?

Comment: @javanoob It's extremely unlikely that will be the limitation with merge statements. You can only act on up to three records per statement.

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce your DML statements by up to half by using the alternative format for merge, which takes a single record and two related records:

```
Account master = dups.remove(0);
Account[] children = new Account[0];
while(!dups.isEmpty()) {
    while(!dups.isEmpty() && children.size() < 2) {
        children.add(dups.remove(0));
    }
    try {
        merge master children;
    } catch(DmlException e) {
        // Report an error
    }
    children.clear();
}
```

As for the first loop-within-a-loop, you could use a map for efficiency:

```
Map<String, Account[]> dupList = new Map<String, Account[]>();
for(Account record: allMasters) {
    if(!dupList.containsKey(record.DunsNumber)) {
        dupList.put(record.DunsNumber, new Account[0]);
    }
    dupList.get(record.DunsNumber).add(record);
}
```

As far as making it batchable? I wouldn't. Instead, use Queueable to continue as long as you have more work to do:

```
List<Account[]> accounts = dupList.values();
System.enqueueJob(this);

...

public void execute(Database.QueueableContext context) {
    doMergeLogic();
    if(!accounts.isEmpty()) {
        System.enqueueJob(this);
    }
}
```

Queueable is a lot more appropriate than batchable in this case, because you don't know how many DML statements you need, and batchable's size can't be dynamically changed midway.

Comment: Sounds like a one-off job here where the priority is to get it done as quickly as possible. Nice efficiency tips though. And an interesting note about Queueable vs. Batchable.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah, the database and system interfaces you'd use to script queueable, schedulable, or batchable can't be implemented without actually having a compiled class saved in the database. You'll just either get compilation errors, or if you really force the issue, an Internal Server Error.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm saying, they'd have to go through the whole development/deployment cycle, so involving a proper class which implements any of those interfaces may be more effort than it's worth in the short term

Comment: @sfdcfox and Adrian - next time you two are in Palo Alto, happy hour is on me!  Both of your answers are incredibly helpful. Thank you sfdcfox for the education here, i did not know those things.  Adrian that's exactly what I need, but I asked the wrong question and sfdcfox helped illustrate that. Choosing his answer so that it rises to the top to help others who face similar confusion.